# Can't do multiple for /f commands

Tags: batch-file

I want to do a program for my friend and when i try to do more for /f commands it just dont work!

Code:

```
echo something1 > Settings.dll
echo something2 >> Settings.dll
echo something3 >> Settings.dll
for /f "skip=0" %%a in (Settings.dll) do set something1=%%a
for /f "skip=1" %%a in (Settings.dll) do set something2=%%a
for /f "skip=2" %%a in (Settings.dll) do set something3=%%a
echo %something1% %something2% %something3%
Pause>nul
```

But the output is : something1 something1 something1

Comment: Interesting... I get `something 3` 3 times...You can delete `"skip=0"`btw... It should be causing an error right now. However `for /f %%a in (Settings.dll) do echo "%%a"` This works to echo out each line if that helps...

Comment: I want to teach program my name, age and how many times it was opened and i need to do set something.

Comment: `skip=0` is not accepted by `for /F`, an error arises...

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to read some lines from a file it's easier to use redirection.

To save

```
(
  echo John Smith
  echo 22
  echo 1
) > settings.txt
```

To load

```
(
  set /p name=
  set /p age=
  set /p times=
) < settings.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

…and using the For loop:

```
For /F "Delims=" %%I In (Settings.dll) Do (If Not Defined Line1 (Set Line1=%%I
    ) Else (If Not Defined Line2 (Set Line2=%%I) Else (
            If Not Defined Line3 Set "Line3=%%I")))
Echo= %Line1% %Line2% %Line3%"
Pause>Nul
```